What are the meaning of CCR, CCB, and SSK on a Fujifilm camera?

When I press the DISP button on my Xt5 camera, it shows these information
What is the meaning of the acronyms CCR, CCB and SSK on the LCD? (the lowest row)
I searched the Fujifilm manual, but I could not locate any explanation.

I don't own this camera so this is a guess, but I think it makes sense (even though the manual is definitely lacking).
Based on making up acronyms from things I found in the online manual, I'm going to suggest:
CCR - Color Chrome Effect
CCB - Color Chrome Blue
SSK - Smooth Skin Effect
These should all be in the Image Quality Menu (still photography).  You should be able to verify all of this by turning the options on and off and seeing what shows up when you press "Display"

There's an online manual for the X-T5, with information on the playback menu settings here:
https://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t5/playback/menu_playback/
If you scroll down to the section on Raw Conversion, there's a list of settings that can be adjusted when converting pictures from RAW to another format. You can cross-check the abbreviations from the camera's screen against the list here.
